# Retrieve field value using PHP + Search API + Views?

Tags: search, views

I haven't had this problem in the past but I'm trying to retrieve a field value in a Views PHP Field for a view I made for Search API. I'm using the code below but I tried with 'nid' as well.

```
$stream = $data->_field_data['vid']['entity']->field_stream['und'][0]['value'];
```

You can see the var output here. I'm trying to get field_stream but am having no luck...

http://www.ovwrc.com/waste-search?search_api_views_fulltext=poop%20poop

Answer (score 0):

Run $data though [dmp](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) to inspect the array and see what values are available.

[Search Krumo](https://drupal.org/project/search_krumo) may be useful as I expect that array will be huge!

Comment: As you can see here: http://pastebin.com/5dBtyYkL the entity field is blank. I'm starting to loose hair over not being able to print this field.

Comment: So if the field your after isn't in $data look else where. Not quite sure how your populating it but is there a different hook you can use?

Comment: The field is there, you can see in the pastebin that it shows $field_stream and the correct value, but the entity is blank so I think that's why my code in the original question doesn't work. Is there another way to access that field.

Comment: I've got it working. I'm not sure how I missed this but I was sure I tried it: $row->$field_stream provided me the value. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working :)